# rsync mirror files-from

Tags: linux, rsync

The following command copies files recursively from $MIRROR_SOURCES relative to $MIRROR_SOURCE to $MIRROR_DEST; but the delete flag does not work.

```
rsync -var --files-from=$MIRROR_SOURCES --delete $MIRROR_SOURCE $MIRROR_DEST
```

Comment: Are there any files in `$MIRROR_SOURCES` that aren't in `$MIRROR_SOURCE`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: no. sources contain a list of directories that are present and then rsync recursively copies the files in those listed directories.

Comment: Then what do you expect it to delete?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I expect it to delete files from DEST that are not present in SOURCE. Eg. A mirror copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read **--delete** in `man rsync` carefully, emphasis mine:

> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but **only for the directories that are being synchronized**.  You must have asked rsync to send the whole directory (e.g. "dir" or "dir/") without using a wildcard for the directory’s contents (e.g. "dir/*") since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus gets a request to transfer individual files, not the files’ parent directory.  **Files that are excluded from the transfer are also excluded  from  being deleted unless you use the --delete-excluded option** or mark the rules as only matching on the sending side (see the include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES section).

Bottom line of the story is that it only does this for what you specified to be synchronized and dependent on whether you specified a wildcard or not, if you don't want that but instead want to have it happen everywhere, then you can specify the `--delete-excluded` flag as well.